# How to convert pdf file and extract data from them on a server?

Tags: android, pdf, client-server

The Result of Our Exam Uploaded on Our University website in pdf format and this contain results of all the students of university contain 100-150 pages of pdf ..A guy uploaded An app on play store in which we can see our result of exam  instead of downloading pdf and searching our enrolment no in that ...When i I asked that guy over gmail how u made this he gave me a hint - he said We basically process the PDFs on our server and provide results to the application through our own API. I want to know what this mean and how it is done .. i want to learn this ???

Comment: Question has nothing to do with Android. You upload a PDF file to a server, and there's something there that processes it. Asking for libraries is off topic for Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe one way you could do this would be the following:

1. Use a program to process PDF to extract text. Use a program like the paid Adobe Acrobat or free programming libraries like PyPDF2. If you are using python you can install it by typing "pip install PyPDF2"
2. Process data and put into some form of Collection i.e. map/dictionary.
3. Create a Web API, perhaps using SpringBoot and make a simple controller to look up the request.  I think you can still host it free on [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/pricing)
4. Code your android app to access the Restful API and make the call based on your criteria.